# Ajax request printing the entire html page (ExpressJS)

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, mongodb, express

I am making an ajax request to a router, that router will find a data in the database and return to the same page. But instead of getting the database object, I am receiving the entire html page printed in the console in the client side, in the server side I get the right object. I have looked to others similar questions, but couldn't find an answer. I would appreciate any help.

My router:

```
router.get('/usuario/receber', function(req, res) {
        Redacao
        .findOne({})
        .then(doc => {console.log(doc), res.render('usuario', doc)}) 
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          res.status(500).send({ message: err });
        });
});
```

My view:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#target').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        function successCallback(responseObj){
            console.log(responseObj);
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "/users/usuario/receber",
            type: "get",
            success: function(response){
                successCallback(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using `res.render` to send a response, which will return a rendered HTML string to the client. If you wish to return using a JSON string instead, you can use [res.json](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json)

```
router.get('/usuario/receber', function(req, res) {
        Redacao
        .findOne({})
        .then(doc => {console.log(doc), res.json(doc)}) 
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          res.status(500).send({ message: err });
        });
});
```